# Merge list of maps by UUID

Tags: clojure

I have two list of maps

```
(def map1 ({:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0", :book/name "AAA"}
           {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3", :book/name "CCC"}))
```

and

```
(def map2 ({:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3", :book/author "John"}
           {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0", :book/author "Alan"}))
```

and I want to merge this maps by UUID to get following

```
({:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0", :book/name "AAA", :book/author "Alan"}
 {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3", :book/name "CCC", :book/author "John"})
```

What way can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn group-by-id [m]
  (->> m
      (map (juxt :book/public-id identity))
      (into {})))

(vals (merge-with merge (group-by-id map1) (group-by-id map2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you had vectors instead of lists, you can use join to merge these sets on matching values:

```
user=> (def map1 [{:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0", :book/name "AAA"}
  #_=>         {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3", :book/name "CCC"}])
#'user/map1
user=> (def map2 [{:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3", :book/author "John"}
  #_=>    {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0", :book/author "Alan"}])
#'user/map2
user=> (clojure.set/join map1 map2)
#{{:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3", :book/name "CCC", :book/author "John"} {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0", :book/name "AAA", :book/author "Alan"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use merge to do that. I renamed the vars to make it a little more clear. Also, I used vectors to represent the collection as that is more idiomatic:

```
(def titles
  [{:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0"
    :book/name "AAA"}
   {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3"
    :book/name "CCC"}])

(def authors
  [{:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3"
    :book/author "John"}
   {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0"
    :book/author "Alan"}])

(def prices
  [{:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3"
    :book/price 25}])
```

I created a prices var in order to show that the vectors don't need to be the same size. The first step would be to group each book info in one structure, and then we can use [merge](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge) to get one map per book. To do that, we can use [group-by](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by):

```
(def book-info-by-uuid
  (group-by :book/public-id (concat titles authors prices)))
```

Which will give us a map with uuid's as keys and a vector with all the info of each book as values:

```
{#uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0"
 [{:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0"
   :book/name "AAA"}
  {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0"
   :book/author "Alan"}]

 #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3"
 [{:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3"
   :book/name "CCC"}
  {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3"
   :book/author "John"}
  {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3"
   :book/price 25}]}
```

Finally, we use merge to obtain the result:

```
(map #(apply merge %)
       (vals books-by-uuid))

({:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c0"
  :book/name "AAA"
  :book/author "Alan"}
 {:book/public-id #uuid "555b6f35-4e8c-42c5-bb80-b4d9147394c3"
  :book/name "CCC"
  :book/author "John"
  :book/price 25})
```